# order marker inside tradingview candle

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, trading, tradingview-api

How can i add marker (for my buy and sell orders) inside the candle ,like the image

[image]

currently my chart is showing like this (using getmarks function)
[image]

my getsmarks function

```
 getMarks(symbolInfo, from, to, onDataCallback, resolution) {
    
    if (localStorage.bnApiStatus.toString() == "true") {
        let symbol = symbolInfo.name;
        if(this.self.getclosedOrders){
            this.self.getclosedOrders().then((closedorders) => {
                var result = [];

                if (closedorders.length) {

                    closedorders.forEach(function(row, i) {
                        let label, text, border, background;

                        if (row.side == 'BUY') {
                            label = 'B';
                            text = 'BUY';
                            border = '#00c853';
                            background = '#00c853';
                        } else if (row.side == 'SELL') {
                            label = 'S';
                            text = 'SELL';
                            border = '#EA0070';
                            background = '#EA0070';
                        }
                        i = i + 1;
                        var el = {
                            id: i,
                            color: { border: border, background: background },
                            time: row.time / 1000,
                            text: text,
                            label: label,
                            labelFontColor: '#fff',
                            minSize: 8
                        }
                        result.push(el);
                    });
                    onDataCallback(result)
                }


            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err)
            });
        }
    }   

}
```

i don't know the exact function , so i just try the createShape,createMultipointShape function but i didn't get the exact result.